# Python - evaluate elements of a list subset

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list containing booleans:

```
my_list = [False, False, False, True, True, True]
```

I want to evaluate if for a given tuple with (start, end) indexes the list contains a `True` value, e.g.

```
contains_true(my_list, (0,0)) => False
contains_true(my_list, (0,2)) => False
contains_true(my_list, (0,3)) => True
contains_true(my_list, (3,5)) => True
contains_true(my_list, (5,5)) => True
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
def contains_true(my_list, indexes_tuple):
    start = indexes_tuple[0]
    end = indexes_tuple[1] + 1
    indexes = range(start, end)

    for i in indexes:
        if my_list[i]:
            return True
    return False
```

Is there a better way to do this in Python?

Comment: what about do the intersection between your list and a list defined by [true] or [false]?

Comment: changed list name to `my_list` since `list` shadows the builtin

Comment: I would advice you to use half-open ranges by default. The answers below use `[start, end+1]` to get your answer, but if your tuple `(0,3)` meant include elements 0, 1 and 2 then the answers would have been easier. [Some arguments are here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-October/008188.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = [False, False, False, True, True, True]
>>> def contains_true(seq, bounds):
        start, end = bounds
        return any(seq[start:end+1])

>>> contains_true(my_list, (0,0))
False
>>> contains_true(my_list, (0,2))
False
>>> contains_true(my_list, (0,3))
True
>>> contains_true(my_list, (3,5))
True
>>> contains_true(my_list, (5,5))
True
```

Comment: +1. I like this as it's nice and clear, except the capital `L` for the variable name - local variables like arguments are `lowercase_with_caps` according to pep8.

Comment: @Lattyware PEP8 says `When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead.` Also don't you mean `lowercase_with_underscores`?

Comment: Is `L` a convention for naming a list in python?

Comment: @armandino I like to think so but it's not written down anywhere. More people use `lst`, `data` and things like that

Comment: @jamylak Wow, dunno how I managed to get `lowercase_with_caps` - and you are right, that is recommended. That said, I'd have gone for `seq` as that's what a lot of the built in functions use.

Comment: @Lattyware Haha I agree, I will change it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
def contains_true(data, indices):
     return any(data[indices[0]:indices[1] + 1])
```

The function [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) returns True if the given iterable contains `True`. The above function slices your list and returns True if the slice contains at least one True value. This gives your expected results:

```
contains_true(my_list, (0,0)) => False
contains_true(my_list, (0,2)) => False
contains_true(my_list, (0,3)) => True
contains_true(my_list, (3,5)) => True
contains_true(my_list, (5,5)) => True
```

Comment: This won't quite behave as the asker wants - if you see his examples, he wants the end boundary plus one.

Comment: @Lattyware: Thanks, I've added a +1 to give the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 :

```
contains_true = lambda L, (start, end): any(L[start:end+1])
```

Or in Python 2 & 3:

```
contains_true = lambda L, start_end: any(L[start_end[0]:start_end[1]+1])
```

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware that you could use function argument names like this

Comment: Why use `lambda`? This would look a lot better as a `def`. I'm not sure if this is a better style than my solution... it seems pretty good.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I was unaware of that as well so I guess that means that my way is the accepted way.

Comment: @Simeon Visser : sorry, I forgot about that. I added a Python 3 version.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an off by one error.

> There is also a variation on this that says there are two hard things
>   in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one
>   errors.

Your list of examples shows that the 'end' is *inclusive*, `(0,0)` and `(5,5)` both select sublists of length 1.

But the `range(0,0)` and `range(5,5)` treat the second 'end' as *exclusive* and `range(0,0)` and `range(5,5)` are empty lists of indices.

You need to add 1 to the 'end' index of the range call to make your code work as intended.

Is there a better way?  You could use `import itertools` and `itertools.islice` to get the sublist and pass this to the `any` function.  Is this better for you?

Comment: This isn't an answer - the question is if there is a better way, not to explain the problem with his existing code. This would suit more as a comment.

Comment: @Lattyware - true, and this is why I appended my itertools suggestion in parallel to your comment.  Cheers.

Comment: @Chris Thanks! good catch. I lost it simplifying the example.

Answer (score 0):

your List should be a numpy array, so:

```
import numpy as np
```

Then your function could look like this:

```
def contains_true(list,tupel):
    if l[tupel[0]:tupel[1]].any()==True: 
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: Do you mean _tuple_? And, couldn't you just write `return l[tupel[0]:tupel[1]].any()`?

Comment: or more simple `retrun l[tupel[0]:tupel[1]].any()`

Comment: Don't use `list` and `tuple/tupel` as names since you are shadowing the bult-ins